# Application.js.coffee rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I am trying to do an autocomplete from jQuery, however the code that I have is in CoffeeScript. I am not to sure how to run it on my localhost server.

At first I placed it in application.js but that doesn't work, so then I created gens.js.coffee and placed the code there, but still doesn't show.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#querysearch').autocomplete
    source: ['foo', 'food', 'four']
```

Here application.js is calling the file:

```
//= require gens
//= require jQuery.ui.datepicker
# file his actually gens.js.coffee
```

This is how I call application.js:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added something like `console.debug('yes, I'm here!');` to `gens.js.coffee` and checked your browser console when loading the page? Said more directly: have you proven whether or not `gens.js.coffee` is being included in `application.js`?

Comment: Is `gem "coffee-script"` in your `Gemfile` and uncommented? Is the gem installed *(did you run `bundle install` to ensure it's installed?)*

Comment: Do you have a precompiled copy of `application.js` built already? Run `rake assets:clean` to clear out any precompiled copy.

Comment: thanks i know coffee doesn't work at all, i am checking it right now. Try them however nothing else is different!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I would make sure that I have the CoffeeScript and jQuery UI gems in my Gemfile.

```
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end
```

Then I would make sure I was requiring these assets correctly. I think you are making mistakes here

1. by capitalizing the `Q` in jquery.
2. by requiring datepicker then trying to call autocomplete
3. by requiring your jQuery UI library after your 'gens' file.

It should look like this

```
//= require jquery.ui.autocomplete
//= require gens
```

You can place JS code (NOT CoffeeScript) straight into the `application.js` file if you like or it should be ok in your `gens.js.coffee` file.

You could also try running your server and visiting `http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js`. You can look at the JS there and see if it looks correct.

I would also try to open Dev tools in the Chrome browser and look for JavaScript errors.