# Javascript Coffeescript won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

I can't seem to have coffee script works. I am trying a simple auto complete with jquery.

Here the code i have that i am trying to implement an autocompletion on

```
<%= form_tag "/search", :method => "get" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], :value => "Search for people.", :class=>"searchbox", :onclick=>"this.value='';", :id => "querysearch" %>
  <%= image_submit_tag("site/blankimg.png", :name => nil, :class=>"searchbox_submit" ) %>
<% end %>
```

The auto completion has to be on the text field, and call the following coffeescript to run it

```
jQuery ->
  $('#querysearch').autocomplete
    source: ['foo', 'food', 'four']
```

Now when i run the server, nothing work however i do see if i check my source code on the link the following script

```
(function() {

  jQuery(function() {
    return $('#querysearch').autocomplete({
      source: ['foo', 'food', 'four']
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

Now i do not know if the coffeescript was executed, in my gem file i have the following

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'devise'
gem "RedCloth", "~> 4.2.9"
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem "paperclip-ffmpeg"
gem 'geocoder'
gem "coffee-script"
...
```

I also try the following comment from this posts [Application.js.coffee rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682471/application-js-coffee-rails) but i am not sure if there is anything else wrong?

Comment: Do you see any JS errors in the console?

Comment: How do i see js errors? i am using google chrome

Comment: It's View > Developer > JavaScript Console on OS X

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined

Comment: if ((localStorage["firstRun"]!="false") && (localStorage["firstRun"]!=false)){
  chrome.tabs.create({url: "welcome.html", selected:true})
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined
  localStorage["firstRun"] = false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but shouldn't...

```
jQuery ->
  $('#querysearch').autocomplete
    source: ['foo', 'food', 'four']
```

Be...

```
jQuery(document).ready ->
  $('#querysearch').autocomplete
    source: ['foo', 'food', 'four']
```

Your current implementation actually calls jQuery as a function instead of attaching a callback handler.

Comment: I don't think it work, if i try it, i see the the html output with no source, unlike railcasts.